# Julia syntax error @kwdef with default value as string

Tags: macros, julia

This code produce a syntax error. I cannot use a default value in a @kwdef struct?

```
@kwdef struct MyStruct
    indir::String = "./",
    outdir::String = "./result",
    threshold::Int = 2
end


ERROR: syntax: invalid assignment location ""./result"" around REPL[16]:1
```

Comment: @kwdef does not want commas separating the lines. Running the same code without commas after each field fixes your error.

Comment: Perfect. I'll write a short answer below for future  readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@kwdef` is a macro in julia that defines a struct, and automatically creates an associated constructor.

Normally, to create a struct and constructor, one would write:

```
struct Foo
    paramWithoutDefaultVal::String
    paramWithDefaultVal::String
end
Foo(paramWithoutDefaultVal; paramWithDefaultVal="Default Text") = Foo(paramWithoutDefaultVal, paramWithDefaultVal)

julia> Foo("Specified Text")

       Foo("Specified Text", "Default Text")

julia> Foo("Specified Text", "Also Specified Text")

       Foo("Specified Text", "Also Specified Text")
```

But the macro `@kwdef` increases readability by simplifying this slightly.

The same struct and constructor can be defined, using `@kwdef` with:

```
@kwdef struct Bar
    paramWithoutDefaultVal::String
    paramWithDefaultVal::String = "Default Text"
end

julia> Bar("Specified Text")

       Bar("Specified Text", "Default Text")

julia> Bar("Specified Text", "Also Specified Text")

       Bar("Specified Text", "Also Specified Text")
```

Note: In both examples, there are no commas between parameters. The code provided in the question was breaking due to the commas being included. `@kwdef` uses the same syntax as a struct definition, so it should not have commas.